# incorrect string to date conversion swift 3.0

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am converting a format like 10/24 12:00 PM in string to the equivalent in Date format. I am using the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd hh:mm aa"

   self.dateCompleted = dateFormatter.date(from: self.DeliverBy!)
```

dateCompleted is a Date variable whereas self.DeliveryBy is a String variable.

I am getting an output like 2000-10-24 17:00:00 UTC where as it should be something like 2017-10-24 12:00:00 UTC.  Am i doing something wrong?

I referred http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: `DateFormatter` assumes local time unless told otherwise. So seeing 17:00:00 UTC makes perfect sense assuming you live in EST (UTC -5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date string does not specify a *year,* which is therefore
determined from the *default date.* What you can do is to set the
default date to the (start of the) current day:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd hh:mm aa"
dateFormatter.defaultDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
if let dateCompleted = dateFormatter.date(from: "10/24 12:00 PM") {
    print(dateCompleted) // 2017-10-24 10:00:00 +0000
}
```

(I am in the Europe/Berlin timezone, therefore 12:00 PM is printed
as 10:00 GMT.)

Comment: 2017-10-24 17:00:00 +0000 I am still getting incorrect time stamp

Comment: @Ackman: Note that a Date has no timezone and is always printed in GMT.  "12:00 PM" in your time zone is 17:00 in the GMT timezone, so the result is correct. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the current date info into the DateFormatter:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd hh:mm aa"

dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date() // start with the current date

self.dateCompleted = dateFormatter.date(from: self.DeliverBy!)
```

Comment: 10/24 12:00 PM ----->Deliveryby
2017-10-24 17:00:56 +0000----->dateCompleted why is there a time difference?