# Comparing Time in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, time

I am getting two date string in this format, "08:00:00" coming from server side as a starting slot or ending slot. I have to get the time of local timezone and then check if the current time lies in between the time interval which is coming from server. 
But I am unable to do the comparison.

```
func checkTime() -> Bool {


            let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "PKT")


            let startingSlot = self.selectedArea.startingSlot! //UTC
            let endingSlot = self.selectedArea.endingSlot! //UTC
            let date = Date().description(with: Locale.current)
            let current = date.split(separator: " ")
        let currentD:String = String(current[5])

            let date1: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: startingSlot)!
            let date2: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: endingSlot)!
        let currentdate:Date = dateFormatter.date(from: currentD)!

            print(date1)
            print(date2)
            print(current)

            if(currentdate >= date1 && currentdate <= date2) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
```

I expect to get true if the current date time lies in between the date1 and date2.

Comment: If you `print(date1, date2, Date())` then you should see the problem.

Comment: @Sumyia, Can you can you provide the date string you are receiving from server?

Comment: Most probably the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/47682631/1187415.

Comment: startingSlot String? "09:00:00" some
endingSlot String? "03:00:00" some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the time by ignoring the date component -

```
func checkTime() -> Bool {

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PKT")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let startingSlot = "2000-01-01 08:00:00" //UTC
let endingSlot = "2000-01-01 23:00:00" //UTC

let date = Date()

let date1: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: startingSlot)!
let date2: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: endingSlot)!

let currentTime = 60*Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date) + (Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date)/60) // in minutes
let time1 = 60*Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date1) + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date1) + (Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date1)/60) // in minutes
let time2 =  60*Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date2) + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date2) + (Calendar.current.component(.second, from: date1)/60) // in minutes

print(currentTime)
print(time1)
print(time2)

if(currentTime >= time1 && currentTime <= time2) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

}

Output-

> 1121
>   510
>   1410
>   true

Comment: I am updating my code in question. The main issue is of time zone. when I convert my date using dateformattor it attaches a dummy date value with it and hence creates the issue.

Comment: currentdate Date 1999-12-31 23:42:19 UTC 
date2 Date 2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC 
date1 Date 2000-01-01 08:00:00 UTC