# I'm converting my current date with timeIntervalSince1970. In which timezone am I receiving it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am converting my current date with `timeIntervalSince1970`

In which timezone am I receiving it?
Currently I'm in Dubai timezone; is this converted date in UTC Format?

```
let epochTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date: A Date value encapsulate a single point in time, **independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone.**

Comment: Possible helpful: [NSDate() or Date() shows the wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time).

Answer (score 7):

A `Date` is an absolute point in time. It does not have a time zone. If you started a stopwatch at "00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970," the result of `timeIntervalSince1970` would be the number of seconds that had elapsed on that stopwatch. It doesn't matter if you take that stopwatch on a plane and fly anywhere in the world. You could fly to the Moon. It doesn't matter. The same number of seconds will have elapsed (ignoring relativistic effects and the occasional leap second to keep it in sync with the Earth's changing rotation speed).

Time zones only matter when you want to turn that absolute point in time into a human-readable string (in which case you use a `DateFormatter`) or when you want to convert it into calendar units (using `DateComponents` and a specific `Calendar`).

A lot of confusion comes from printing `Date` objects, which come out with something like "2018-11-15 14:19:27 +0000" but that doesn't mean the point of time is "in" the "+0000" time zone. This is just a handy format for displaying to programmers to assist in debugging. If you want a string, you must use a `DateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value from `timeIntervalSince1970` is a TimeInterval (aka Double) since the date '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' in seconds that elapsed until the specific timestamp.

Comment: You are right, sorry :( Deleted that part. Is at least the rest of my answer correct?