# Creating a date with DateComponents

Tags: swift, calendar, nsdatecomponents

I want to get the first day and the last day of the week. But my results do not match the documentation from apple:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1410442-weekday

This is my function:

```
func startAndEndDateOfWeek(weekOfYearWithYear: (week: Int,year: Int)) -> (start: Date, end: Date) {
    var output = (start: Date.init(), end: Date.init())

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var firstDayComponents = DateComponents()
    firstDayComponents.weekOfYear = weekOfYearWithYear.week
    firstDayComponents.yearForWeekOfYear = weekOfYearWithYear.year
    firstDayComponents.weekday = 1

    let firstDay = calendar.date(from: firstDayComponents)

    var lastDayComponents = DateComponents()
    lastDayComponents.weekOfYear = weekOfYearWithYear.week
    lastDayComponents.yearForWeekOfYear = weekOfYearWithYear.year
    lastDayComponents.weekday = 2

    let lastDay = calendar.date(from: lastDayComponents)
    output = (start: firstDay!, end: lastDay!)
    return output
}
```

.weekday = 2 -> leads to the sunday and not 0.

[image]

I also want to have the entire day and not 16:00.

Comment: A `Date` is always printed in UTC – see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time. You are probably in the GMT+8 timezone.

Comment: okay makes sense, but do you have any idea why creating the date with the dayComponents does not really work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. In the Gregorian calendar, weekday = 1 means Sunday; weekday = 2 means Monday; etc. You can look at `calendar.maximumRange(of: .weekday)` to get the range of valid values, and you can look at `calendar.weekdaySymbols` to see what these `weekDay` values mean (e.g. “Sun”, “Mon”, “Tue”, “Wed”, “Thu”, “Fri”, and “Sat”).
2. You said:

   > I also want to have the entire day and not 16:00.

   A `Date` object references a moment in time. So it can’t represent an “entire day”. But it can represent midnight (and midnight in your time zone is likely 4pm in GMT/UTC/Zulu).

   You can, alternatively, return a `DateInterval`, which does represent a range of time.

   ```
   func interval(ofWeek week: Int, in year: Int) -> DateInterval {
       let calendar = Calendar.current

       let date = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, weekOfYear: week, yearForWeekOfYear: year).date!
       return calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: date)!
   }
   ```

   And then

   ```
   let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
   formatter.dateStyle = .short
   formatter.timeStyle = .short

   let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
   let dateInterval = interval(ofWeek: 2, in: year)
   print(formatter.string(from: dateInterval))
   ```

   In a US locale, the interval starts on January 6th:

   > 1/6/19, 12:00 AM – 1/13/19, 12:00 AM

   Whereas in a German locale, the interval starts on the 7th:

   > 07.01.19, 00:00 – 14.01.19, 00:00
3. If you want the start of the first day of the week and the last day of the week, you can do:

   ```
   func startAndEndDate(ofWeek week: Int, in year: Int) -> (Date, Date) {
       let date = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, weekOfYear: week, yearForWeekOfYear: year).date!
       let lastDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: date)!

       return (date, lastDate)
   }
   ```

   And then

   ```
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateStyle = .short

   let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
   let (start, end) = startAndEndDate(ofWeek: 2, in: year)
   print(formatter.string(from: start), "-", formatter.string(from: end))
   ```

Comment: Setting `weekday = weekDayRange?.first (== 1)` does not take into account that a week starts on a Monday in some regions (like Germany). It might be better *not* to set that component for the first date, and compute the second date by adding one week minus one day.

Comment: if I use the users current Calendar like Calendar.current, it does not handle the users region right? so basically I have to handle all the various calendar the user might use? Or what would be a more general solution?

Comment: @MartinR - You’re right. I’ve updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @PaFi - No, I’d definitely suggest always using `Calendar.current`. Someone using a non-gregorian calendar will see very unusual results, if you don’t. Definitely test your code using non-gregorian calendars and different locales.

Comment: A German user will see "07.01.19, 00:00 – 14.01.19, 00:00". `Calendar` and `DateIntervalFormatter` have a `locale` property, the default value (probably) is the current locale which can be modified in the system prefs.

Comment: @Willeke - Of course it will. I was focusing on Martin’s point, how the definition of of the week changes from locale to locale. But obviously, the formatting of the formatter’s resulting string also varies.