# Truncating time off a date retains some time component

Tags: swift, xcode, date, swiftui, locale

Writing a simple date extension:

```
extension Date {
    public func removeTimeStamp() -> Date {
        guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)) else {
            fatalError("Failed to strip time from Date object")
        }
        return date
    }
}
```

I get:

```
2020-11-11 13:00:00 +0000
```

Notice again it has added an hour, but to the afternoon, not the morning even.

I would expect

```
2020-11-11 00:00:00 +0000
```

EDIT:
Focused question on the date truncation component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSDate() or Date() shows the wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time)

Comment: Not really. In parts. It still doesn't explain how when I use the extension to truncate the time off the date, it still retains 13h00 on the time component. What I am trying to achieve is to find dates within the last seven days, day aligned.

Comment: Because `print` displays the date always in `UTC(+0000)` and your time zone is obviously `UTC+1300`. Wow that's pretty far away from Greenwich  The output `2020-11-11 00:00:00 +1300` and `2020-11-11 13:00:00 +0000` are the same point in time. Use a date formatter to get the local date and time.

Comment: Just avoid to `print()` the date. As I said use a date formatter to display the date. The date calculations are going to be fine.

Comment: Ok, it took some time to get through. But I got it.

Comment: @Slappy `date.description(with: .current)`