# Getting next day date from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker

I'm working on `UIDatePicker`. I have set panama time in my System for date is 18/11/2020 & time is evening 11:00 pm. When I get date, so it is giving me 19/11/2020 instead of 18/11/2020 & it's a wrong.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time

Comment: @Sweeper, Thanks for replay, Let me check.