# Swift - Date formatter not working as expected

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

I am writing code to convert two dates from strings to date objects however this is not working as expected for some dates that I pass on to the date formatter.

Here is my code:

```
let stringDateMinimum = "00:00 " + year + "-0" + String(month+1) + "-01"
let stringDateMaximum = "00:00 " + year + "-0" + String(month+2) + "-01"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm yyyy/MM/dd"
        
        
let minimimDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateMinimum)
let maximumDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateMaximum)

print(stringDateMinimum)
print(minimimDate ?? "")
print(stringDateMaximum)
print(maximumDate ?? "")
```

This is the output from in the console:

```
00:00 2022-03-01
2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000
00:00 2022-04-01
2022-03-31 23:00:00 +0000
```

If you compare lines 3 and 4 in the console, you can see that the string inputted into the date formatter does not match the output of the date formatter when it should.

Comment: `2022-03-31 23:00:00 +0000` ***is*** `00:00 2022-04-01` in your timezone (the UK, I'm guessing?). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937019/nsdate-or-date-shows-the-wrong-time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Sweeper for your comment. The answer was to include a time zone in the string I was inputting into the date formatter. So for example I changed the date format to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm yyyy/MM/dd Z"
```

and added +0000 for my timezone to the stringDateMinimum and stringDateMaximum

Comment: Note that this will result in UTC time not local time.

Comment: And be careful with this code. If you are getting the month and year from the current timezone and generating a UTC Date